# Getting the path of an image

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, mime

i have created an activity with mime type as image as below.

```
<activity android:name=".xxxx"                        
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">                        
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:host="xxxx.xxxx.net"></data>
                 <data android:mimeType="image/*" />            
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:host="xxxx.xxxx.net"/>
                 <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

now when the user clicks a photo and goes to gallery and does share my app is coming there and when he clicks it im able to launch the above activity...now my question is how to get the path of that image?

Comment: You mean you want path of image from gallery???

Comment: For this question, it would be suitable to provide the receiver's (and related) code since you say that your manifest is set up correctly.

Comment: yup when the activity gets launched i need to get the path of that image

Answer (score 6):

This will give you the path in an Uri instance in your *.xxxx* `Activity`

```
Uri uri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Then, if you need to display the image in an `ImageView`, use this:

```
imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

**Optional Code:**

If you also need the *absolute path* of the Image on the device (I found this a necessary constraint when I upload Images to Twitter using the TwitPic API), then the following code will give you the *absolute path* of the image on the device in a `File` instance. Since this bit is unclear in the OP, I figured a little extra code won't hurt. ;-)

```
// PASS THE URI INSTANCE FROM THE CODE ABOVE IN THE CONSTRUCTOR
File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri));
```

And the method `getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri)`:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}
```

And to set the image using the File file instance:

```
imageView.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent resultData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

    Uri selectedImage = resultData.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

            uploadImagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            bitmapUploadImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uploadImagePath);
            profileImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapUploadImage);
            cursor.close();

}
```